# Correct way of implementing a Time Trial version for iOS apps

Tags: ios, trialware, time-trial

Apple has finally accepted submissions of Time Trial versions for Apps and in their [latest guidelines, at paragraph 3.1.1](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) they do recommend implementing them as FREE In-app purchases ("Non-Consumable IAP item at Price Tier 0").

I have done so, but now it is not clear to me how to prevent a user from doing trials ad infinitum, by simply uninstalling the app, reinstalling it and RESTORING the Free in-app purchase!

Is there any way of preventing it?

I believe that any flags that we programmatically save in `NSUserDefaults` would be deleted if the app is manually uninstalled together with all data. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck):

> Using the DeviceCheck APIs, in combination with server-to-server APIs, you can set and query two bits of data per device, while maintaining user privacy.
>   You might use this data to identify devices that have already taken advantage of a promotional offer that you provide, or to flag a device that you've determined to be fraudulent.

Comment: No other solution that doesn’t require implementing a server?

Comment: @jeddi you could try to save your flag in [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services), it will persist even after the app is uninstalled and install again.

Comment: Interesting option! Would it require user approval to be saved in the keychain?

Comment: @jeddi No, it does not require user permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the receipt and extract `Purchase Date` of the In-App purchase for the free trial. See [Receipt Fields](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW15). Even if the item is restored, the date will correspond to the original purchase date.

Comment: Actually it doesn’t work. transactionDate reports a different date every time the app is reinstalled! How can I get the date of the very first installation?